# need to add apostrophes between arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a music page with CDs besides the title. I also have the list:

`"artist, upcoming artist, producer, featured artist and featured beatmakers"`

So each music cd listed says:

> "the title by the artist (if any), the upcoming artist (if any),
>   producer (if any), external artist (if any) and external beatmakers(if
>   any)"

Here is the problem..
If there is an artist AND an upcoming artist, or an external artist and a producer or any combination of arrays, then I need to put a space and apostrophe between the two different arrays or any combination of the arrays listed above.....

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
<?php the_title(); ?> By <?php echo themex_artists(get_post_meta($post-ID,'freealbum_artists',true)); ?> 
<?php echo themex_artists(get_post_meta($post->ID,'freealbum_upcomingartists',true)); ?> 
<?php echo themex_artists(get_post_meta($post->ID,'freealbum_producers',true)); ?> 
<?php echo themex_artists(get_post_meta($post->ID,'freealbum_externalartists',true)); ?> 
<?php echo themex_artists(get_post_meta($post->ID,'freealbum_externalproducers',true)); ?>
```

Each album is different so the names don't always show for every field on every album all the time....
I need some way to separate these properly. Any advice would be great!

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed an example of exactly what you wanted the output to look like.

Comment: @TomFenech in the question "the title by the artist (if any), the upcoming artist (if any), producer (if any), external artist (if any) and external beatmakers(if any)"

Comment: i want the output to look like "the title - by the artist (if any) [, <- apostrophe if needed cause there is more names to list] the upcoming artist (if any) [, <- apostrophe if needed cause there is more names to list] producer (if any) [, <- apostrophe if needed cause there is more names to list] external artist (if any) [, <- apostrophe if needed cause there is more names to list] and external beatmakers(if any) [, <- apostrophe isnt needed here]

Comment: For the record, **,** is a comma, **'** is an apostrophe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put this info on an array instead first as you say, filter non-empty values and finally implode the array with a comma:

```
$all_fields = [
    'freealbum_artists',
    'freealbum_upcomingartists',
    'freealbum_producers',
    'freealbum_externalartists',
    'freealbum_externalproducers'
];

$album_fields = [];
foreach ($all_fields as $field) {
    $album_fields[] = trim(themex_artists(get_post_meta($post->ID, $field, true)));
}

echo implode(', ', array_filter($album_fields, function ($val) {
    return $val ? true : false;
})), PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: where would i add this?
would i just write it n the same spot startng with <?php and ending with ?>

Comment: Nice, I was about to do something almost exactly the same :) As all of the fields begin with "freealbum_", you could remove that from the `$all_fields` array and put it into the loop. Also you may want to use a test for `empty` rather simply `$val ?`.

Comment: Actually, your `array_filter` callback could simply be `array_filter($album_fields, 'strlen')`

Comment: @TomFenech good point about the `empty` test, but I think they return exactly the same for all cases, same with `strlen`. What I feel is necessary is adding a `trim` there, though.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, try this (assuming the functions returns FALSE if there is nothing to display):

```
<?php the_title(); ?> By <?php echo themex_artists(get_post_meta($post-ID,'freealbum_artists',true)); 
echo themex_artists(get_post_meta($post->ID,'freealbum_upcomingartists',true));

if(themex_artists(get_post_meta($post->ID,'freealbum_upcomingartists',true)) && themex_artists(get_post_meta($post->ID,'freealbum_producers',true))) echo ", ";

echo themex_artists(get_post_meta($post->ID,'freealbum_producers',true));

if(themex_artists(get_post_meta($post->ID,'freealbum_producers',true)) && themex_artists(get_post_meta($post->ID,'freealbum_externalartists',true))) echo ", ";

echo themex_artists(get_post_meta($post->ID,'freealbum_externalartists',true));

if(themex_artists(get_post_meta($post->ID,'freealbum_externalartists',true)) && themex_artists(get_post_meta($post->ID,'freealbum_externalproducers',true))) echo ", ";

echo themex_artists(get_post_meta($post->ID,'freealbum_externalproducers',true)); ?>
```

Is that what you meant :) ?